# What is the correct way to configure apache superset to connect to presto via LDAP?

Tags: presto, apache-superset

I started a new Apache Superset deployment from their docker-compose.

My connection string looks like this:

```
presto://user:password@presto:8446/
```

And in Advanced/Security I put this:

[image: Apache Superset - Security]

But this doesnt seem to work.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I tried to follow the `pyhive` connection string as much as possible.

And yes... PyHive is installed in my docker image. I checked.

When I click on "Connect" I am getting this error.

```
An error occurred while creating databases: (database_name) A database with the same name already exists
```

When I click on "test Connection" i get the following error

```
ERROR: (builtins.NoneType) None
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/dbapi)
```